# i want that webp urls are arranged in the same order as jpg urls

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

webp urls have the same names as jpg urls. i want that webp urls are arranged in the same order as jpg urls. they're in Y2:Y17 in google sheets. jpg urls are in Y2:Y9 and webp urls are in Y10:Y17. each url ends by a query parameter like ?v=1680797131. i want this to be done with one formula. i don't want to do anything else just enter one formula and it do the job.
this formula works well to arrange just the first webp to be at the same order as the first jpg: =FILTER(Y10:Y17,REGEXMATCH(Y10:Y17,REGEXEXTRACT(Y2,"(.+).jpg")&".webp")).
i want a formula to arrange all the webp not just the first
this is the google sheets link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10hUY03TzMUTm5E0CmztiicaEixEck_CXRLV58Q16gzU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The range `Y10:Y17` is blank in all tabs of your sample spreadsheet. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170125/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also remove unnecessary tabs and data in your sample spreadsheet and show just the relevant data there, together with your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the text string `.jpg` in those URLs with the text string `.webp`, and make the results clickable links, use [regexreplace()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) and [hyperlink()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093313), like this:

```
=arrayformula( hyperlink( regexreplace(Y2:Y9, "\.jpg", "\.webp") ) )
```

Comment: thanks this works but webp urls are not with their query parameter. this this formula they are with query parameter:

Comment: Understood. The problem is that those requirements remain unclear in the question. Please observe that Stack Exchange sites are not "help forums" nor "discussion boards" but **wiki** sites that use the Q&A format. See [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Expected Behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). To improve the question, [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170125/edit) it and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score -1):

this is the formula that did the job:
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(Y2:Y9,"^(.+).jpg"),{REGEXEXTRACT(Y10:Y17,"^(.+).webp"),Y10:Y17},2,FALSE), ""))

- the first link will be displayed as a formula on fx. to make it a link:
  copy it / right-click on an empty row / choose past special and choose values only / select the link (displayed as text) / right click / insert link / past it / apply

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).